# Is climbing in basketball according to the rules?

Tags: rules, basketball

Imagine me, climbing and sitting on someone's(teammate) shoulders. We are standing near opponents basket. I get a pass and since i am at 3 meters height, i cannot be blocked and most probably i will score.

Is this illegal? If yes, according to what rule?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Climbing on a teammate is illegal.

In the NCAA, this is a Class B technical foul.  When this occurs, two free throws are awarded to any member of the other team.

From [NCAA Men's Basketball 2013-14 and 2014-15 Rules](http://www.ncaapublications.com/p-4312-2013-14-and-2014-15-mens-basketball-rules.aspx), Rule 10 (Fouls and Penalties), Section 4 (Class B Technical Infractions):

> **Section 4. CLASS B TECHNICAL INFRACTIONS**
> **Art. 1.** A technical foul shall be assessed to a player or a substitute
> for the  following infractions:
>
> b.
> Climbing on or lifting a teammate to secure greater height.
>
> **PENALTY:  Article 1 and Article 2.a through i. Two free throws shall
> be  awarded to any member of the offended team. All infractions  count
> toward ejection but do not count toward the team-foul  total or
> disqualification.**

In the NBA, this is considered an Illegal Assist in Scoring, and results in a loss of the ball.

From [Official Rules of the National Basketball Association](http://www.nba.com/analysis/rules_index.html), Rule 10 (Violations and Penalties), Section XIII (Illegal Assist in Scoring):

> **Section XIII-Illegal Assist in Scoring**
> a. A player may not assist
> himself to score by using the basket ring or back-board to lift, hold
> or raise himself.
> b. A player may not assist a teammate to gain height
> while attempting to score.
> PENALTY: Loss of ball. The ball is awarded
> to the opposing team at the free throw line extended.

Comment: What about FIBA rules? I tried to find something about it but failed.

Comment: @PabloH I've looked through the [FIBA official rules](http://www.fiba.basketball/documents), and I couldn't find a rule against this, either.  Do you play FIBA?  You should try getting on the shoulders of a teammate, scoring a goal, and report back to us what happens.  :)

Comment: Hahaha, no; played when a kid, too old and unfit now. Besides jumping on a (passive) teammate, as in Australian football, another possible move is actively hand-supporting a teammate as they do when throwing from the line in rugby. Assists like these would also be useful for blocking.

Answer (score 3):

From FIBA Rules Interpretations (31 Jan 2019): https://www.fiba.basketball/rules/interpretations.pdf

"25-7 Statement. It is a violation to lift a team-mate to play the ball.

25-8 Example: A1 embraces his team-mate A2 and lifts him up under the opponent’s basket. A3 passes the ball to A2 who dunks the ball into the basket.
Interpretation: This is a violation. The goal shall not count. Team B shall be awarded a throwin from the sideline at the free-throw line extended in its backcourt."